# Grouping DataFrame, filtering by group size and by value of column in one line?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrame, `df`, where I want to groupby `'columnA'`, filter for members of groups with `len >= 3`, and select members with the value *pizza* in `'columnB'`.

The following line

```
df.groupby('columnA').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)['columnB'] == 'pizza'
```

returns the indices of all rows with a boolean in `'columnB'`.

This works of course:

```
df2 = df.groupby('columnA').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)
df2 = df2[(df2['columnB'] == 'pizza')]
```

**But can I do this in one line?**

Comment: try `...filter(lambda x: len(x)>=3 and x["columnb"]=="pizza")...?

Comment: I think I'm getting `TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool`

Comment: I think `df.groupby("columnA").filter(lambda x: len(x)>=3).query("columnB=='pizza'")` may work for you.

Comment: Yep, that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lambda provided solution in comments:

```
df.groupby("columnA").filter(lambda x: len(x)>=3).query('columnB=="pizza"')
```